# Regular expression checking max digits and precision

Tags: regex

I need to create a Regex that allows negative numbers with 1 to 24 digits (if it is an integer) or numbers with 1 to 24 minus decimal digits (up to 12 decimal digits).

Example of valid numbers:

```
123456789012345678901234
123456789012.345678901234
-123456789012345678901234
-123456789012.345678901234
```

Example of invalid numbers:

```
1.12345678901234567890
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I didn't votedown you. But I don't understand this: "numbers with 1 to 24 minus decimal digits (up to 12 decimal digits)."

Comment: What I mean is: if the number of digits after decimal point is 12, the number of digits before the decimal point must be 12. It's kind of a formula: X (total numbers) = 14, A (digits before decimal point) = X - B (digits after decimal point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do:

```
^-?(?=(\d\.?){1,24}$)\d+(\.\d{1,12})?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yM9rZ8)**

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. PS: At this moment I know that I need to study Regex 100x more. lol

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira Don't feel stupid -- this is a pretty tricky regexp, using an advanced feature in a very clever way.

Answer (score 0):

This works for your example:

```
^-?\d{2,12}\.?\d{1,12}$
```

Comment: You'll need an anchor to the end of the string too: `$`.

Comment: Not quite right -- if there are N digits after the decimal, you can have up to 24-N digits before it, e.g. 16.8 and 20.4.

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lX1wZ9)

```
^-?(?:\d{0,24}|(?!.{26,})\d*\.\d{0,12})$
```

**Explanation**

```
^             (?# assert start of string)
-?            (?# match optional -)
(?:           (?# start non-capturing group)
  \d{0,24}    (?# match up-to-24 digits)
 |            (?# OR)
  (?!.{26,})  (?# negative lookahead assertion to prevent 26+ characters)
  \d*         (?# match 0+ digits)
  \.          (?# match . literally)
  \d{0,12}    (?# match 0-12 digits)
)             (?# end non-capturing group)
$             (?# assert end of string)
```

---

The thing mine has that others doesn't is the `(?!.{26,})` assertion.  This is used in the alternation with decimals.  If we want to limit decimals to 12, and the entire amount of digits to 24..then we can't have any more than 25 characters in the string.

Comment: See his comment above. The number of digits allowed before the decimal depends on how many are after it.

Comment: @Barmar I believe I have followed his needs..you can't have more than 12 digits after the decimal, and the total number of digits can't be more than 24.  So `X = A + B`, `B <= 12` and `X <= 24`.  My expression follows this.

Comment: I see. Lookaheads can be confusing. :)

Comment: True that. It took me a while to get the zero-width assertion down.  If you narrow this expression to `^(?!.{26,})\d*$` it will match 0+ digits, but right after the starting anchor we will do a zero-width assertion making sure there are no more than 26 characters ahead of that spot.  So technically this is the same as `^\d{0,25}$`.